# Executing a java class in the linux terminal without the java command

Tags: java, linux, command

I have a java class, cs.class, that I would like to execute from the command line, just as you use any other command. I would like to be able to type 'cs file1' etc. Without having to use 'java cs file1'. How can I do this?

edit: I would also like this to work if I put my class anywhere in my path.

Comment: Follow this instructions and you can run java on terminal: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15333/run-java-classfile-from-terminal

Comment: You could create an alias for `java cs`

Comment: Thanks Tarsis Azevedo and Remimeus. I combined both of your ideas and added 'alias cs='java -cp /home/user/bin/ cs'' to my .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this](http://javacompiler.sf.net) will work for you on linux.

Answer (score 0):

> For Windows

Create a file named custom.cmd and add the following to it

```
@echo off
DOSKEY cs=java cs $*
```

Now

> right click your command prompt shortcut->properties->shortcut tab->and append the following to your target field
>
> /K C:\custom.cmd

my custom.cmd resides in C:, change the path to yours
Now you can use "cs" as a command within that cmd shell. You can mention you filename as an argument as well as $* specifies command line arguments.